# Trailing stop loss price reversal on entry candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a pine script which calculates trailing stop price and the problem is when the entry is made the trail stop shifts downward if the price reverses immediately after the entry is made and resulting is loses to be huge for intraday move and risk remains open naked.

Below is the code and what the best can be done so that I can exit with a fixed stop loss if price reverses on the first candle.

```
////////////////////////////////////
TSL_STOP_BUY = input.int(title = "TSL_STOP_BUY", defval = 150, minval = 1, maxval = 10000, step = 1)

TSL_STOP_SELL = input.int(title = "TSL_STOP_SELL", defval = 150, minval = 1, maxval = 10000, step = 1)


longstopprice = 0.0

shortstopprice = 0.0


longstopprice := if (strategy.position_size > 0)

    stopvalue = close - TSL_STOP_BUY

    math.max(stopvalue,longstopprice[1])  
else
    0

shortstopprice := if (strategy.position_size < 0)

    stopvalue = close + TSL_STOP_SELL

    math.min(stopvalue,shortstopprice[1])
else
    9999999

    if indicatoroptionF
        strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = buywI, comment = "B")
        if tralingstoploss
            strategy.exit("long", from_entry = "long", stop = longstopprice, comment = "TSL EXIT BUY" )
    if indicatoroptionG
        strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, when = shortwI, comment = "S")
        if tralingstoploss
            strategy.exit("short", from_entry = "short", stop = shortstopprice, comment = "TSL EXIT SHORT" 

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```